# Develop the following function into a series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Develop the following function : (here is how they start, and I am totally lost, I shall put what I  did as a comparison at the bottom)

Edit: can someone explain the first two steps under this line, what did they do?
$$\frac{x}{x-2}$$
$$\frac{x}{x-2} = 1 +\frac{2}{x-2}$$
I understand what they do starting from here:
$$\frac{x}{x-2} = 1 -\frac{1}{1-x/2}$$
They finish with this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^n (\frac{-1}{2^n})x^n$$

This is what I wanted to do :
$$\frac{x}{x-2}$$
factor out x
$$\frac{x}{x-2} = 1 +\frac{1}{1-2/x}$$
I finish with this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^n (\frac{2}{x})^n$$

I appreciate the help with this! One of the last things to learn before my exam tomorrow.

Comment: Do you want to do that for small $x$ or infinitely large $x$ ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @PMF, Sorry, I should of made it more clear, I don't understand the first two steps that they did and why.

Comment: Presumably "they" are asking for a power series in x. What you end up with (N.B. the "factor out x" step is wrong) is a power series in $1/x$. And what's with the $=$ signs in the two series? That does not make any sense.

Comment: Recall $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: @ Nick, sorry for the = sign, I removed it. I realize the factor out x step is wrong, and you are correct, they are asking for the power series in X. (I'm french, and translating math is kind of hard lol!). Could you explain out what they did in the first two steps under my edit in the post?

Comment: Perform polynomial long division on $x/(x-2)$ and you end up with the second line.

Comment: You look right, the first answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to write a function as power series, i.e something of the form $\sum_{n}^{+\infty} a_n x^n $. It is crucial to know in what set you require the equality to to be true (or, similarly, to restrict *a posteriori* yourself to the biggest interval on which the equality is true). Of course in this case we want use the identity $\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n $, this motivates "their" approach: they want to rewrite the initial function as something that contains a fraction $\frac{1}{1-g(x)}$. However, the final answer is a little different:
$$ -\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} -\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n $$
whence:
$$ \frac{x}{x-2}=1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} -\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n  $$
if $|\frac{x}{2}| < 1$.